# ES6 Find the maximum number of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following data

```
shots = [
    {id: 1, amount: 2},
    {id: 2, amount: 4}
]
```

> Now I'm trying to get the object which has the highest amount

I've tried using reduce like follows

```
let highest = shots.reduce((max, shot) => {
    return shot.amount > max ? shot : max, 0
});
```

But I'm always getting the lowest number. 
Any idea what I might be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `shots.reduce((max, shot) => shot.amount > max.amount ? shot : max)`

Comment: you need to return the value from reduce. also, you should have an initial value for reduce

Comment: Can your amount have negative values as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two problems here, the first is that a reduce needs a return value. the second is you're comparing a number with an object.

Therefore, I think you need something like this:

```js
// This will return the object with the highest amount.
let highest = shots.reduce((max, shot) => {
    return shot.amount >= max.amount ? shot : max;
}, {
    // The assumption here is that no amount is lower than a Double-precision float can go.
    amount: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
});

// So, we can convert the object to the amount like so:
highest = highest.amount;
```

### Edit:

A clean short one liner would look something like so:

```js
const highest = shots.sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount)[0]
```

Comment: This one breaks upon all negative values since you are compared a number to undefined. `-4 > undefined` for example is false, whereas in this case -4 would be the highest number. It is therefore not really the best answer. And you lose the `id` property in the process as well

Comment: Sorry to say but for a negative number this will still break. `-4 > 0` => `false` so your code would return `0` if the only entry in the array has amount `-4`

Comment: @RogierSlag - *raises hat to you* Thanks again, changed to min safe int

Comment: Getting closes but not yet ;) Imagine there is a single item in the array, whose amount is Number. MIN_SAFE_INTEGER. The code snippet above would return the seed instead of the actual number. So you'd lose the id of that object using this method. Also depends on the requirement of the function: is two numbers are equal and both highest, should you return the first or the last?

Comment: @RogierSlag - This conversation has made my day, thank you! Hopefully I've got it now!

Answer (score 18):

Cleaner 2 lines solution :)

```
const amounts = shots.map((a) => a.amount)
const highestAmount = Math.max(...amounts);
```

**Update**

Code above will return the highest amount. If you want to get the object that contains it, you will face the posibility that many objects contain the highest value. So you will need `filter`.

```
const highestShots = shots.filter(shot => shot.amount === highestAmount)
```

Comment: I like that! Smart

Comment: Nice and elegant, a simple way of finding the object would then be: `const highest = shots.find(e => e.amount === highestAmount)`

Comment: The only issue is here we're only getting the highest amount back, not the object itself, right?

Comment: Yeah only the highest amount. But if you need the object I guess you should reconsider and rethink the complexity of what you are doing (what you are trying to achieve). Imagine if you have more objects with the same amount (highest). You really wanna get ALL of them?  If you do so : `var highestShots = shots.filter(shot => shot.amount === highestAmount)` will do it.

Comment: Note that for any moderately sized array, Math.max(...amounts) could result in "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Updated**

```
let highest = shots.reduce((max, shot) => {
  return shot.amount > max.amount ? shot : max
}, {amount:0});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly enough most answers here do not properly consider all cases

1. The seed value is off
2. The comparison is going between different types

To properly handle negative values, you would have to seed with `-Infinity`

Secondly compare the largest value of that point with the new value

You'd get the following:

```
highest = shots.reduce((max, current) => current.amount >= max.amount ? current : max, {amount: -Infinity})
```

You can test this with

```
shots = [
    {id: 1, amount: -2},
    {id: 2, amount: -4},
    {id: 3, amount: -4},
    {id: 4, amount: -5},
]
highest = shots.reduce((max, current) => current.amount >= max.amount ? current : max, {amount: -Infinity}) // Returns id 1, amount -2

shots = [
    {id: 1, amount: 2},
    {id: 2, amount: 4},
    {id: 3, amount: 4},
    {id: 4, amount: 5},
]
highest = shots.reduce((max, current) => current.amount > max.amount ? current : max, {amount: -Infinity}) // Returns id 4 amount 5
```

Note that if the array is empty, you will get a value of `{amount: -Infinity}` as a result, so you might want to handle the case where `shots.length === 0` before the reduce

Answer (score 1):

You could check the amount property of both items and return the item with the greatest amount.

```
let highest = shots.reduce((a, b) => a.amount > b.amount ? a : b);
```

For same amount, you get the first object with the same amount only.

It does not work with an empty array.

If you like all objects with the same highest `amount`, you could reduce the array with with two conditions.

```
let highest = shots.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r || o.amount > r[0].amount) return [o];
        if (o.amount === r[0].amount) r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, undefined);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the object has more than two items, I'm right?

Comment: @BrianVanegasParra, then you need a different approach and an array as result set. please see edit.

Comment: Your answer is fine, I have the problem that was not contextualized

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes

- return `shot.amount` instead of `shot`
- simply return the **value after comparison**

Finally

```
shots.reduce((max, shot) => 
    shot.amount > max ? shot.amount : max, 0);
```

**Demo**

```js
var shots = [
    {id: 1, amount: 2},
    {id: 2, amount: 4}
];
var output = shots.reduce((max, shot) => 
    shot.amount > max ? shot.amount : max, 0);
console.log( output );
```

**Edit**

If the **entire object has to be returned**, then *initializer* should be an object with `amount` property

```
var shots = [
    {id: 1, amount: 2},
    {id: 2, amount: 4} ]; 
var output = shots.reduce((max, shot) => 
    shot.amount > max.amount ? shot : max , {amount:0}); 
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to return the complete object that has the highest amount, won't this just return the amount only?

Comment: Thank you! There is an answer above, but I'm sure yours will also work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It will simply return the highest amount.

```
Math.max.apply(Math,shots.map((shot)=>{return shot.amount;}));
```

Comment: They're looking for the object, not just the amount, but a neat solution